# Unable to get autoId value into jobId object, here the localStorage autoId is a string

Tags: jquery, cypress

Unable to get autoId value into `jobId` object, here the localStorage `autoId` is a string. Could someone please advise about the problem here ?
I am trying to find the table row based on the jobId and checking if the `jobRow [columnPosition] ==  value` then assert it ...

note: *I am trying to optimize and reduce the code lines as much I can.*

```
  let tableDatacy = "Reports_Table";
  let columnName= "Customer";
  let checkCase = "should";
  let value  = "Main Customer";
  let jobId = {};
  
  const columnPosition = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}]`)
      .find(`th:has(a:contains(${columnName}))`)
      .index()
  console.log("Get the silly index !: "+columnPosition)

  cy.getLocalStorage('autoId').then(autoId => jobId = autoId.jobId);
  let jobRow = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > tbody > tr :contains(${jobId})`);

  if (checkCase === "should" && jobRow [columnPosition] ==  value){
    result = "true";
    expect(result).to.include("true");
  } else if (checkCase === "should not" && jobRow.length == 0) {
    result = "false";
    expect(result).to.include("false");
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one asynchronous line and all the rest are synchronous, so whatever depends on `jobId` should go inside the `.then()`.

Otherwise the synchronous code will ***all*** run before the asynchronous line completes.

```js
const columnPosition = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}]`)
    .find(`th:has(a:contains(${columnName}))`)
    .index()
console.log("Get the silly index !: "+columnPosition)

// Make async call and everthing that needs the result 
// must be inside the callback

cy.getLocalStorage('autoId').then(autoId => {

  jobId = autoId.jobId

  // let jobRow = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > tbody > tr :contains(${jobId})`);
  let jobRow = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > tbody > tr:has(td:contains(${jobId}))`);

  // if (checkCase === "should" && jobRow [columnPosition] ==  value){
  const jobRowText = Cypress.$(jobRow).find('td').eq(columnPosition).text()
  if (checkCase === "should" && jobRowText === value) {
    result = "true";
    expect(result).to.include("true");
  // } else if (checkCase === "should not" && jobRow.length == 0) {
  } else {
    result = "false";
    expect(result).to.include("false");
  }

});
```

---

**Selecting the row**

So `tr :contains(${jobId})`

means "give me the child of `tr` that contains `jobId`, result is `td`.

but `tr:has(td:contains(${jobId}))`

means "give me the `tr` that has a `td` which contains `jobId`".

---

**Selecting the column in the row and comparing the text**

The `jobRow` isn't an array, it's an element so you need to use more jQuery to extract the text to compare.

```js
const jobRowText = jobRow.find('td').eq(columnPosition).text()
if (checkCase === "should" && jobRowText === value) {
```

OR combine

```js
let jobRowText = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > tbody > tr:has(td:contains(${jobId}))`)
  .find('td').eq(columnPosition).text()
```

---

**Cypress commands way**

```js
cy.contains('[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > tbody > tr', jobId)
  .find('td').eq(columnPosition)
  .invoke('text')
  .then(jobRowText => {

    if (checkCase === "should" && jobRowText === value) {
      result = "true";
      expect(result).to.include("true");
    } else {
      result = "false";
      expect(result).to.include("false");
    }
  })
```

Comment: Will try that soon and reply back

Comment: When I set `jobId = autoId.JobId ` it was not working, so i have to change to `jobId = autoId`

Comment: But at this line `let jobRow ` I am getting `0: td.nameMaxWidth.clickable.saveBackLink
length: 1` but I need to get <tr> right inorder to pass columnPosition ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot for reference.

Comment: Ok, yes agree - you want to find the row that has `jobId` in one column and assert true or false if it has `value` in column number `[columnPosition]`. To do that I think you can use `:has()` again.

Comment: Yes based on the jobId I need to find the row and then find the column has the value in column number` [columnPosition]`

Comment: Thank you, when i set a break point at this line  `if (checkCase === "should" && jobRow [columnPosition] ==  value)`  it is just exiting after that ...
could see tr and could see columnPosition value...

Comment: Appreciate your reply.. thank you very much ..I have upvoted and accepted

Comment: You're too kind.